# Books on digital image encryption

Tags: encryption, image

I'm an applied mathematician that recently developed an interest in digital image encryption. Might there be a book or set of references that develops the theory of digital image encryption and introduces the state of the art?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for lists, products and resources are off-topic as the answers could go on forever.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "digital image encryption". An encryption algorithm can generally work with completely arbitrary data, including images. A cipher doesn't care if you're encrypting an image, a video, audio, a string of zeros, or the text from a public domain book. All it cares about is the bits and bytes.

Comment: Hmmm... If you want to compress and encrypt the images, I think that knowing something about the structure of natural images would help. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @AidanRocke For compression, absolutely (though it's more about what human eye's can perceive than image structure, as this allows compression to be lossy). For encryption, it doesn't really make a difference. There's really no need for a type of encryption that only works on a very specific type of data when we have fast and secure algorithms that work on any data, and it would create a risk that it might be used for the wrong type of data and leak information.

Comment: @AidanRocke If a cipher was vulnerable if it didn't take into account the structure of the plaintext, it would be considered fatally broken.